# Sending AMQP messages from an IBM Mainframe

Tags: amqp, zos

We are looking to put a mainframe on a bus. I believe it is AS400. To do this I want to have the CICS Mainframe send an AMQP message to a broker. There are dozens of AMQP Clients including JMS client. I don’t know enough about what is possible on a mainframe to say if I can use one of these client to send an AMQP message from the mainframe to a broker.  Has anyone done this and if so any advise in doing this?

Comment: If it's CICS, it's almost certainly not AS/400.  You'll need to find out from their admin which OS they're running, as there are several (z/OS, z/VM, Linux, etc).  That will determine the availability of AMQP software.

Comment: Thank you. I have found that the OS is z/OS 1.13 RSU1304

Comment: I you are executing CICS on an IBM i (formerly AS/400) here few manuals that can help https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzahg/rzahgcics.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[IBM i](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/) series (AS/400) are not mainframes.  They are considered a midrange machine.  The [IBM z](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/) series are mainframes.

I regularly use [Apache ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/) on the IBM i.  It has excellent [Java](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahg/rzahgjava.htm) support with the IBM JDK.

It is my understanding that the IBM z series also has excellent Java support.

IBM also offers [Websphere MQ](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/wmq/) but I can't find any information on whether it supports the [AMQP](http://www.amqp.org/) protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your answer we are using a JVM on the z series. We will have COBOL call via JCICS into the Java program to send the AMQP message to the broke. Then we will do the opposite to call a COBOL program.